# MongoDB update is slower with relevant indexes set

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

I am testing a small example for a sharded set up and I notice that updating an embedded field is slower when the search fields are indexed.

I know that indexes are updated during inserts but are the search indexes of the query also updated?

The query for the update and the fields that are updated are not related to any manner.

e.g. (tested with toy data) :

```
{

 id:... (sharded on the id)

 embedded :[{ 'a':..,'b':...,'c':.... (indexed on a,b,c),

               data:.... (data is what gets updated)
            },
            ...
           ]

}
```

In the example above the query for the update is on a,b,c
and the values for the update affect only the data.

The only reasons I can think is that indexes are updated even if the updates are not on the indexed fields. The search part of the update seems to use the indexes when issuing a "find" query with with explain.

Could there be another reason?

Comment: please your example of the indexed keys and the keys you are updating.

Comment: The indexes are updated if they need to be - which is if the document moves because it grows too large for its size allocation. It'd be easier to tell if this might be going on if you include an example of the actual update that you're doing. Note that updating multikey indexes is especially bad because you need to update one index entry per array value.

Answer (score 0):

I think wdberkeley -on the comments- gives the best explanation. 
The document moves because it grows larger and the indexes are updated every time.
As he also notes, updating multiple keys is "bad"....I thinks I will avoid this design for now.